# How to change `void *` type to `string` type

Tags: c++, c++11

I have supplied code from a demo and the type associated with the fonts are of type `void *`.

Here is the type of the font as declared in vscode

```
#define GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18 (&glutBitmapHelvetica18)
Expands to:

(&glutBitmapHelvetica18)
```

I am trying to write a quick little conditional to check whether the font is from a list or not.

```
if (find(begin(fonts), end(fonts), reinterpret_cast<char*>(font) ) != end(fonts))
```

I am using an iterator to iterate through an array of strings.

```
    array<string, 7> fonts = { 
      "GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24", 
      "GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10", 
      "GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12",
      "GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_10",
      "GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13",
      "GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15" };
```

My issue is that since all the elements in that array are strings it is throwing a type error between the `void *` and the `string`. I am not too sure how to cast the type to a `string` or if there is a better way of checking if that `void *` is within the array or even a simple list of possible options.

Comment: Are you stating that you're implementing a callback from a C library, and you expect that `void *` to be actually pointing to a `std::string`? What is `glutBitmapHelvetica18`? Is it a `std::string`. It is impossible to determine what's going on based on the information in your question, so it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you until you [edit] your question until it meets all requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Comment: How does taking an address give a `void*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18` is a pointer to an object representing a bitmap font. It's not a pointer to a string, or to the name of the font.

You can do what you're asking, but you're going to want to have an array of `void*` representing the fonts:

```
array<void*, 7> glut_fonts { 
  GLUT_BITMP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, 
  GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10, 
  GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12,
  GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_10,
  GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,
  GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15 
};
```

Now, we can use `find` like you want:

```
if (find(begin(glut_fonts), end(glut_fonts), font) != end(glut_fonts)) {
    // Do stuff if the given font exists
}
```

We can also use this to get the name:

```
array<string, 8> font_names = { 
  "GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24", 
  "GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10", 
  "GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12",
  "GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_10",
  "GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13",
  "GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15",
  "[unknown font]"
};

// Get the index of the font
// std::distance comes from <iterator>
auto index = distance(begin(glut_fonts), find(begin(glut_fonts), end(glut_fonts), font))

string name = font_names[index];
```